# Что такое фиктивное голосование и как оно может повлиять на меня?

Tags: поддержка, faq, репутация

Заметил, что пропала репутация. Во вкладке «Репутация» в профиле пользователя, я вижу неожиданное аннулирование голосов. Вместо стандартного названия вопроса в нем указано: «голосование отменено».

- Что это значит и чем это вызвано?
- Почему я теряю баллы репутации?
- Есть ли возможность как-то вернуть потерянные баллы?

<sub>Перевод вопроса «[What is serial voting and how does it affect me?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126829/274323)».</sub>

Answer (score 16):

#### Что такое фальсификация голосования?

Фальсификацией является систематическое [нарушение правил голосования](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130046/when-should-i-vote). Фальсификация чаще всего заключается в следующем: один из участников многократно голосует за или против сразу несколько ваших сообщений в течение короткого промежутка времени. Такое поведение считается нарушением. Система блокирует его.

Если будет замечено массированное взаимное голосование между двумя участниками с двух разных IP (либо такое поведение будет осуществляться в одностороннем порядке), или же ситуация будет выглядеть в целом подозрительно, модератор и/или разработчики могут заняться расследованием причин такого поведения, применяя впоследствии дисциплинарные меры против участников, замеченных в подобных действиях.

#### В каких случаях голосование *за* считается серийным?

Чаще всего, когда вы неожиданно замечаете появление серии голосов «за» свои сообщения, причиной является то, что другой участник пытается увеличить вашу репутацию. Скорее всего, одно из ваших сообщений очень помогло ему, и он считает, что пройдя по другим вашим сообщениям и систематически за них голосуя, он должным образом вас отблагодарит (вероятно, этот участник забыл о существовании [системы конкурсов](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16065/141525)).

Время от времени подобное поведение можно видеть между двумя участниками, договорившимися голосовать друг за друга, либо между одним участником и «клоном», созданным им, чтобы обмануть систему и увеличить свою репутацию (эта стратегия ведет к блокировки доступа к учетной записи).

#### В каких случаях происходит серийное голосование *против*?

По большей части, каждый раз, когда происходит серийное голосование «против», голосующий в корне не согласен с одним из ваших сообщений (в большинстве случаев, ответом, иногда – комментарием). Аналогично случаю с положительным голосованием, несогласный участник проходит по сообщениям автора, систематически «минусуя» их. Иногда такое происходит и по другим причинам – к примеру, ради шутки.

#### Как быть, если я подозреваю, что стал жертвой серийного голосования?

Если фальсификации голосов происходит в настоящий момент времени или только что закончилась, не волнуйтесь: повод волноваться появится только по прошествии 24 часов с того момента, как вы заметите данную активность. Система должна самостоятельно ее обнаружить и аннулировать соответствующие голоса. Пожалуйста, **не пытайтесь** найти решение этой проблемы на Мете или привлекая модератора с помощью флага тревоги. Единственное, что вам могут посоветовать – это дождаться автоматического обнаружения проблемы системой и пересчета голосов.

Если в течении 24 часа подозрительные голоса не были аннулированы, свяжитесь с модератором, используя сигнал тревоги, объяснив ему суть проблемы. В общем случае, желательно, чтобы вы *не сообщали подробностей инцидента* на Мете, так как детали расследования не должны разглашаться, и вы, на самом деле, не получите никакой новой информации, которая могла бы быть полезной другим участникам.

**См. также:**
[What should you do if you're serial downvoted & it isn't automatically reversed within 24 hours?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212332/what-should-you-do-if-youre-serial-downvoted-its-not-automatically-reversed/212339)

#### Как система распознает фальсификацию голосов?

Каждую ночь приблизительно в 03:00 UTC запускается скрипт распознавания фальсификации, который осуществляет поиск подозрительных моделей поведения. В основном, система ищет людей, которые повторно и многократно голосуют за или против сообщений других участников. Количество голосов, достаточное, чтобы привлечь внимание скрипта – невелико (точный алгоритм не разглашается). Когда система обнаруживает подозрительную активность, все голоса, отданные одним из вовлеченных в схему участников другому задействованному в ней участнику, аннулируются: при этом в истории изменения репутации участника-реципиента система выдает сообщение «голосование отменено».

Количество аннулированных голосов может быть произвольным: в расчет принимаются все аннулированные голоса («за» и «против», хотя, как правило, серийное голосование бывает либо полностью «за», либо полностью «против»). Если участник достиг суточного лимита баллов репутации, количество аннулированных баллов может не отображаться – если аннулирование никак не повлияло на его репутацию за текущий день.

#### Способна ли система обнаружить фальсификацию голосования для удаленных сообщений?

Да. Если произошло серийное голосование за одно или более сообщений и некоторые из них были позже удалены, скрипт все равно аннулирует соответствующие голоса.

#### Почему моя репутация изменилась?

Соответствующие баллы репутации были отозваны, так как подобные манипуляции с голосами недопустимы. Полученные в результате фальсификации голоса признаны системой недействительными – следовательно, недействительным признан и соответствующий прирост (или уменьшение) репутации. Единственный способ вернуть репутацию – заработать новые баллы законным способом.

#### Следует ли беспокоиться в случае появления в моей учетной записи сообщения об аннулировании?

Нет, не нужно. Это просто извещение об изменении репутации. В конце концов, мы не можем контролировать действия других участников. Случаи появления участников, которые лично занимаются фальсификацией голосов со своей учетной записи, крайне редки, и, как правило, такие участники получают дисциплинарные взыскания еще до того, как вы получаете извещение об аннулировании. Таким образом, если вы обнаружили в истории изменений своей репутации сообщение об аннулировании голосов, вам не о чем волноваться.

#### Что еще мне нужно знать об этом?

- **Аннулирование голосов ведет к пересчету репутации.**

  Каждый раз при аннулировании серийных голосов репутация за те дни, в течение которых происходило серийное голосование, будет пересчитываться, как если бы такого голосования не было, и все баллы репутации, которые вы могли потерять, если такое голосование приводило к исчерпанию дневного лимита репутации, будут вам возвращены. Таким образом, инициаторы серийного голосования не отнимут у вас заслуженной репутации.
- **Возможно повторное голосование.**

  За сообщения, в которых система аннулировала голоса, позже можно будет проголосовать повторно (если эпизод серийного голосования не повторится и не произойдет повторной отмены).
- **Не существует автоматического наказания, а также уведомлений и предупреждений.**

  В данный момент аннулирование голосов в случаях серийного голосования означает *только* аннулирование. Вы можете обнаружить факт аннулирования, просматривая историю изменения вашей репутации – но это все, что делает скрипт. Не существует автоматической блокировки участников, замеченных в серийном голосовании, и единственное уведомление, которое они получают при аннулировании голосов – это запись в истории изменения репутации, если они голосовали против ответов. Если они голосовали против вопросов, они не получат никакого уведомления вообще.

Многократное воздействие на систему, приводящее к многочисленным аннулированиям, может стать причиной временной блокировки доступа к учетной записи, но процесс принятия решения в таком случае осуществляется человеком, а не системой. Для такого поведения не предусмотрены автоматические флаги тревоги, но модераторы все же имеют доступ к статистике, которая помогает бороться со злоумышленниками. Если вы подозреваете, что стали жертвой серийного голосования в ограниченный промежуток времени, вы можете отмечать свое сообщение флагом тревоги, чтобы привлечь внимание модератора и объяснить ему ситуацию для дальнейшего ее изучения.

Comment: "(вероятно, этот участник забыл о существовании системы конкурсов)." а вероятно не хочет тратить свою репутацию на "благодарность"

Comment: А еще вероятно зашел посмотреть кто ему ответил, увидел еще хороших ответов, начал их плюсовать и увлекся)

Comment: _"приблизительно в 03:00 UTC"_ - именно 3 UTC или 0 UTC = 3 MSK?

Comment: @Qwertiy В оригинале указано "Every night around 03:00 UTC".

Comment: @Qwertiy Да, примерно 03:00 именно по UTC. Все серверное время отсчитывается по UTC. Текущее сервеное время можно видеть в верхней части [меню достижений](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YyvBt.png).