# Если SO открытая и демократичная система, то почему судей при закрытии вопроса мы видим, а голосовавших "за" и "против" нет?

Tags: обсуждение

Закончился мой 3й месяц как зарегистрировался на SO. Не стал брать знак "Фанатик", так как им не являюсь. Но некоторые знаки всё же мне дали. И один из первых это был "Давление общества". Вопрос почему мы не знаем наших тайных стражей в голосах "за" и "против", но знаем судей, закрывших вопрос?

Comment: Чтоб не мстили.

Comment: Так где защита судьям от мести?

Comment: Зашита для проголосовавших за закрытие состоит в том, что кол-во проголосовавших  за закрытие должно быть как минимум 5 участников. В сумме их субъективные голоса приближаются к более объективному уровню оценки. Голос плюс или минус за сообшение это всегда субъективное мнение одного участника.

Comment: Одного или давление общества? Может вы не много противоречие себе

Comment: Вот я зашёл и увидел минус 25 так вот это субъективное мнение или более объективное?

Comment: @0xdb И если защита закрывших вопрос их количество в 5 то почему не выдать список 25 проголосовавших против их же больше чего бояться мести?

Comment: Не совсем понимаю, что вы имеете ввиду. Вы же спрашивали про возможность мести закрывшим вопрос. Если  минусов на сообщении много, то да, можно считать, что сообщение очень низкого качества и мнение проголосовавших против тоже приближается к объективному.

Comment: Посмотрите внимательно я не писал о мести я задавал вопрос про защиту судей. Вы ответом указали что их спасает "объективность". Я же тогда спрашиваю почему тогда не спасает объективность -25?

Comment: Где вы увидели минус 25?

Comment: @Эникейщик возьмите этот к примеру https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24281192/how-to-remove-or-hide-powered-by-text-from-google-translate

Comment: Ведь сайт воспитывает стадное чувство. Вот написал кто-то рейтингом +100500 отрицательный отзыв, остальные тоже солидарны с ним. Чем вам не стадо. Я думал что сайт помогает поделиться знаниями, а в итоге получаем "Давление общества".

Comment: Вопрос хороший, как по мне, так что не понимаю, почему минусят. Это же не предложение, где голоса означают несогласие с вводимой фичей, а обсуждение

Comment: Ну и я о том же. А тут сокрытие анонимность в одном и полная открытость в другом

Comment: Или я на местное табу нарвался? не понятно

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Отличий довольно много.

Закрытие вопроса лишает автора возможности получать ответы. Закрывать вопросы можно только по короткому списку причин. Закрыть вопрос сложно: для этого нужно пять голосов от пользователей с 3К репутации. Столько же голосов нужно для переоткрытия вопроса. Процесс отслеживается через очереди проверки.

Голос «против» сам по себе ни на что не влияет, заминусованные сообщения получают плюсы, заминусованные вопросы — ответы, заминусованные ответы — галочки. Поставить минус можно по любой причине. Минус легко перебивается плюсом, за плюс дается в пять раз больше репутации чем за минус. [Серийное голосование](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4006/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F) откатывается автоматически.

Ощутимое влияние минусы могут оказать только если их много и при этом нету плюсов. Но это как правило говорит о том, что участнику нужно что-то менять со своей стороны.

### Недостающая информация

Считаю что было бы лучше если бы Вы показали сообщение за которое получили «Давление общества» и рассказали для какой цели Вам нужны имена голосовавших против него.

Сейчас остается много вопросов по ситуации.

- Сколько было минусов?
- Были ли они заслуженными?
- Получали ли Вы какие-то комментарии с объяснениями?
- Каким образом имена «тайных стражей» могут Вам помочь?

Если бы Вы включили всю эту информацию в вопрос, то можно было бы подробнее рассмотреть механизм голосования в данной конкретной ситуации.

### Анонимность голосования

Тема анонимности голосования «против» уже неоднократно обсуждалась в сети:

- [Encouraging people to explain downvotes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-downvotes)
- [Anonymous downvotes ruining Stack Overflow for new users, driving them away from a meaningful contribution](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198962/anonymous-downvotes-ruining-stack-overflow-for-new-users-driving-them-away-from/198968)
- [Why are anonymous downvotes allowed?](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5584/why-are-anonymous-downvotes-allowed)

У нас тоже были такие обсуждения, например, [Голоса против без каких-либо пояснений](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277/%D0%93%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%8F%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9).

Создатели сайта остановились на том, чтобы показывать голосующим «против» сообщение. От анонимности голосов (как плюс, так и минус) отказываться не решились, по крайней мере пока. Основные аргументы в пользу анонимности:

- Хорошие ответы и вопросы, как правило, получают больше плюсов чем минусов.
- Анонимность позволяет избежать переходов на личности и мести в отношении голосующих.
- Сохраняется свобода голосования. Люди могут оценить вопрос/ответ не вступая в прямую конфронтацию с его автором.

Иногда возникают неприятные ситуации в которых человек получает кучу минусов без каких-либо объяснений. Но даже в этой ситуации список имен пользователей мало что даст. Если это сильно тревожит можно зайти в чат или на мету и попросить объяснить что с вопросом не так. Так Вы получите либо объяснение минусов, либо компенсацию в виде плюсов.

Если захотите сделать дельное предложение по отмене анонимности, то Вам понадобится объяснить какие конкретные преимущества это принесет и каким образом можно будет избежать лишних конфликтов.

### По пунктам

> Если SO открытая и демократичная система, ...

Ключевое слово «если». SO — сайт с закрытым кодом, полностью принадлежащий частной компании. В механику сайта встроены определенные элементы самоуправления: сообщество может обсуждать вопросы и высказывать мнение. Но конечное слово остается за Компанией, ни о какой демократии речи не идет.

> , то почему судей при закрытии вопроса мы видим, а голосовавших “за” и “против” нет?

Это никак не связано ни с демократией, ни с открытостью. Как правило, в современных демократических государствах люди знают имена судей, который выносят приговоры в судах. При этом на выборах сохраняется анонимность голосования. Никто не знает кто и за кого голосовал и, тем более, никто не несет за это ответственности.

Если хотите сделать предложение по улучшению механики сайта, то лучше опираться не на идеологию (демократия и гласность), а на конкретные примеры и улучшения.

> Не стал брать знак "Фанатик", так как им не являюсь.

У Вас есть знаки «Академик», «Учитель» и «Непризнанный гений». Не думаю что стоит так буквально трактовать названия знаков. :)

Comment: Спасибо хоть один ответ. А то только комменты. Я попозже отвечу на ваши замечания

Comment: Хороший ответ. Добавлю ещё, что чисто с технической точки зрения показывать проголосовавших проблематично. Ладно на ruSO, но на enSO бывают вопросы и ответы с тысячами голосов

Comment: @default-locale "Если бы Вы включили всю эту информацию в вопрос" - я не рассматривал конкретный случай, а задавал конкретный вопрос Почему там есть имена и мы не боимся показывать, а тут есть чего боятся мы скрываем.

в современных демократических государствах люди знают имена судей - потому что это открытость которая не рождает несправедливость.

Comment: Почему нельзя сделать такую же систему для минусования. Тоже с ограниченным выбором ответов?

Comment: Фанатик я понимаю это всё условности. Но что если я им не являюсь? А по остальным нечего сказать  Академик дали за то что в этот день приняли конкурсный вопрос на 300. Непризнанный гений - это вообще не ко мне. никогда себя таким не считал и не считаю. на SO потому что карантин и не против ответить на несколько вопросов. Учитель не знал вообще за что дают

Comment: @AzizUmarov Да, но Вы зачем-то указали случай с [Давлением общества]. Мне стало непонятно какое он имеет отношение к вопросу и я решил на всякий случай уточнить детали. А так, я постарался ответить на основной вопрос и обозначить различия между закрытием и голосованием. Если коротко: голосование происходит чаще и с меньшими последствиями.

Comment: Да спасибо, и на том, что сказать. "Голосование происходит чаще и с меньшими последствиями." не согласен проходит с меньшими если вовсе не голосовать. А любое голосование будет иметь последствия.

Comment: Пожалуйста! С меньшими, имеется ввиду, по сравнению с закрытием вопроса.

Comment: Понимаете я и ответил что это человеческая слабость, не принятие сильными мира сего правоту слабых. Если много конфликтов из-за закрытия то почему они сделали такую систему. Если меньше при анонимном то почему не закрывать анонимно тайно а не с магазина на диване

Comment: Я ведь не за то чтоб менять устои или ещё чего. Пока есть пользователи сайта он будет жить. Про100 есть не мало примеров схода пользователей по политике компании

Comment: Политику (загадочных сильных мира сего) предлагаю оставить в стороне, она к теме не относится. Конфликты из-за закрытия неминуемы ввиду самой природы закрытия. Если человеку закрывают вопрос, то ему *нужно* его переоткрыть, чтобы получить ответ. Тот, кому поставили минус перечитает свое сообщение и исправит его. Или не исправит и пойдет дальше.

Comment: Я в принципе не против изменения функций. Вполне допускаю, что можно построить систему минусования с «объяснением». Такое предложение можно обсудить, особенно если в нем будут учитываться [контраргументы](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357436/) и [предыдущие предложения](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6521). Также можно обсудить предложение сделать голоса за закрытие анонимными, особенно если оно будет дельное и с примерами. Мой ответ о том, что голосование и закрытие — два разных процесса, которые нужно обсуждать отдельно. «Открыли одно — открывайте и другое» не аргумент.

Comment: Думаю да подниму вопрос чтоб добавили стандартные ответы. Когда минусуют чтоб не было голословным только ради того чтоб ответ был более полезным. Ведь система проверок это предлагает за низкокачественные ответы. Разница лишь в том что она будет предлагать улучшить или объяснить причину. В таких случаях думаю не будет смысла боятся чего либо

Answer (score -11):

Я думаю месть как раз таки не причем. Дело не в ней, а в человеческой натуре и слабости. Человек не может явно признаться, что он не согласен. Ведь в этом случае может возникнуть ответственность.

Пример: Кто признается открыто что он "употреблял наркотики" и нарушил этим закон за которым может последовать ответственность. А вот если социолог для своих изысканий задаст тот же вопрос с гарантиями анонимности. Думаю результаты как раз таки будут зависеть от той самой человеческой слабости.

Comment: Минусы без указания причин только подтверждает мои домыслы. Диванные войска и только, ни причин ни аргументов.

Comment: «Я думаю месть как раз таки не причем. ...» Месть — важный фактор, анонимность голосования позволяет избежать войны минусов и постоянной ругани. Ваше сравнение минусов с употреблением наркотиков и рассуждения об ответственности за минуса только подчеркивает важность анонимности голосования.

Comment: Минус за некорректный пример. Пример говорит скорее не о слабости, а о здравомыслии. Какое он имеет отношение к закрытости голосов за/против - тоже непонятно. Упоминание наркотиков выглядит как прием манипуляции в дискуссии при помощи общественно порицаемых явлений.

Comment: Пожалуйста приведите пример "корректный" в чем проблема? А то задаешь вопрос и сам на него отвечаешь. Монолог ёпте. И получаешь минусы - мне ровно я про100 хочу понять почему, а ответ типа боимся мести. Вы ребята реально так думаете. Я вот по своим именем сижу и не выбираю никаких "megapiha" "falos" всевдонимоа боясь что выйдет дядя и постучит по голове.

Comment: Как назвал отец так и хожу, в уважении к нему. А тут страх перед местью на SO меня заминусуют. Ребята в чем проблема ставите минус в чем проблема поставьте ник и причину, если нет ни того ни другого то о чем говорить. Я понимаю что минусы замечания справедливы в большинстве случаев.

Comment: Поставил минус. Человеческая натура -- вещь крайне многогранная, например помимо стадного инстинкта бывают ещё и нонконформисты, вещь совершенно противоположная, которые наперекор другим спокойно скажут своё мнение. И да, представляете как раз среди программистов судя по моим наблюдениям доля нонконформистов выше чем в среднем по популяции. Я не люблю, когда вот так всех под одну гребёнку и навешивают ярлыки, так что не согласен с позицией. Правила -- это то, что оттеняет одни стороны "натуры" и ретуширует другие и на мой взгляд на текущий момент они достаточно оптимальны.

Comment: Так речь не овас шла. В чем проблемы если вы не боясь мести спокойно отвечаете за свои поступки я только за. Я против остальных кто выражают свою мысль одним только минусом. А вопрос в прочем был совсем не. Про то что вы аргументирует свой выбор, а то что сам сайт ведёт двойные стандарты.

Comment: Объясняю свой минус: я несогласен с вами. Между прочем минусы как раз и придуманный для того, чтобы выразить несогласие. Я думаю, что и останльные минусы имеют ту же причину.

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica, уважаю ваше мнение не собираюсь спорить. Просто хотелось бы знать ваше мнение а не только не согласие. Может есть что-то конкретное,замечания, дополнения, ....

Comment: Возможность видеть голоса спровоцирует линшие конфликты между участниками, войны минусов, и будет способствовать троллингу. Вам уже объяснили в общем. Any questions ?

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica, понимаете пока не напишешь ответ, а точнее чушь не найдешь того кто ответит. -9 это как раз таки взгляд. Я хочу донести до сообщества что в основе общества лежит всё же справедливость и не терпимость к не справедливости. Если вы считаете что-то неверным то это ваше право, но хотелось бы знать почему (не вызвано ли это личной или прочей неприязни).

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica если не воспитывать в людях терпимость то она ниоткуда не появится, потому что это не инстинкт с которым мы рождаемся. А вот как раз таки страх это тот с которым мы рождаемся. Так может не нужно бояться минусов как мы не боимся закрывать открыто вопросы?

Comment: вот -9 и что вы видите какую либо агрессию? или что-то ещё, это мнение моё я его описал (действительно ли я так думаю это другой совсем вопрос). Важно спокойно относиться к критике. Соглашаться не обязательно и не зачем, у каждого своё мнение этим и хорош этот мир.